# How to add privacy policy to an android app?

Tags: java, android, google-play-console

I developed an android app and I'm to publish that app in playstore. I added the necessary permissions for ad mob in android manifest file such as INTERNET and NETWORK STATE.But its only for admob.Its a totally offline app and doesnt wantto access the internal storage or anything like that.
So should I add a privacy policy when I upload the app to play store .If i have to do so how to find the privacy policy suitable for my app.Please help. Here are the only permissions I asked.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: you can make privacy policy online or make a doc by your own and upload it to a public git repo, then share that git link url as privacy polity to google play store

Answer (score 1):

While uploading the app play store might ask for privacy policy, there are two solutions which can help you.

1. Download particular format of privacy policy created by some one else , then edit it according to your application and publish it
2. Use an Online Privacy Policy Generator. Answer the questions and the privacy policy will be generated automatically and then edit it if required!
   Examples:

   - [App Privacy Policy Generator](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/)
   - [Free Privacy Policy Generator](https://www.freeprivacypolicy.com/)

After generating the privacy policy, host it and give that URL in the the publishing section of play store developer console

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your policy from here [App policy generator](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/)
2. Add this privacy policy to your website or if you do not have a website create one here [Google sites](https://sites.google.com/a/appwebstudios.com)
3. Now you can add link to your site in your App and on Play Store